# How to get a call graph for the binary code of a contract?

Tags: contract-design, evm, assembly, graphs

I need a call graph generator for the assembler level of smart contract code in order to analyse solidity compiler bugs.

In that way, [porosity](https://github.com/comaeio/porosity) is excatly what I need !
However there are too much bugs : for examples, it doesn’t stop the call graph at `STOP` and `REVERT` instructions and doesn’t treat `STATICALL` as call instructions. It only recognize `JUMPI` as jump instruction and thus ignore `JUMP` instructions. I tried to fix the code for those errors, and [the problems got worst](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/Uniswap.svg).

What’s the alternative way to get what I’m needing ?